# Can Visual Studio 2012 save custom NuGet package sources in the solution?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nuget, artifactory

I am looking at setting up a custom NuGet repository for my organization and I would like the ability to have the package sources saved against the solution so that other developers don't need to manually set up their own package sources, is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, if you make use of the MSBuild based package restore functionality. Detailed steps can be found in this blog post: http://xavierdecoster.com/nuget-package-restore-using-solution-specific

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer Xavier, I completely forgot to accept mine. But I like that you have a guide to accomplish this.

Answer (score 2):

So my problem was that in order for the .Nuget folder to be created automatic restore needs to be enabled by Right clicking on the solution in VS and choosing "Enable Nuget Package Restore" rather than relying on the visual studio option.